# Format string as currency for Google Docs

Tags: string, google-apps-script, formatting, printf

What is the correct string formatting structure for Google Apps Scripts - as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatString(String,Object...)).

Is this about how C formatting works?

*I cannot figure how to write sprintf-like string formatting using '%'-style format strings.*

I am using Google Apps Scripts to copy data from a spreadsheet, process the data in memory, then replace text placeholders in a Google Doc with the processed data.

Some of the data includes numbers, intended to represent currency, and these are placed into tables.

I have written a simple function to format the strings...

```
function formatStringCurrency(tempValue) {
  // Description
  return Utilities.formatString("$%d,%3.2f", tempValue/1000, tempValue%1000);
}
```

and I parse the necessary data through this function to prepare a "currency-like" string.

**My problem - my formatting function works perfectly *unless* the string is over 1,000, and is also a multiple of 1000, that is, does not contain hundreds or less.**

For example, here is a screenshot sample of my current output...

[image: spreadsheet output: first row $2,325.00, $9,300.00, second row $3,0.00, $12,0.00, etc...]

The second row is intended to display $3,000.00 and $12,000.00.

I have thought about formatting the Google Doc table, however that is not yet possible either manually or programmatically.

I have also attempted to remove all formatting from the numbers as they are represented in the original spreadsheet, however this does not make a difference.

As always, any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leading zeros (zeros in the left till have a minimum number of digits) don't work for floats. But this will work

```
function formatStringCurrency(tempValue) {
  // Description
  return Utilities.formatString("$%d,%02d%1.2f", tempValue/1000, tempValue%1000/10,tempValue%10);
}

function examples(){
  Logger.log(formatStringCurrency(1));
  Logger.log(formatStringCurrency(0.1));
  Logger.log(formatStringCurrency(1000));
  Logger.log(formatStringCurrency(100));
  Logger.log(formatStringCurrency(134141));
  Logger.log(formatStringCurrency(32423.43));
}
```

result:

```
[14-07-08 19:47:21:138 HKT] $0,001.00
[14-07-08 19:47:21:141 HKT] $0,000.10
[14-07-08 19:47:21:145 HKT] $1,000.00
[14-07-08 19:47:21:149 HKT] $0,100.00
[14-07-08 19:47:21:154 HKT] $134,141.00
[14-07-08 19:47:21:157 HKT] $32,423.43
```